# Column reference is ambiguous for INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE inside a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table given by the source:

```
create table person (
    id serial not null,
    name varchar(50) not null unique,
    age int not null,
    constraint person_pkey primary key (id)
)
```

And I want to define a function `my_func` that inserts a new record or updates age with the given one. I implemented it like this:

```
create or replace function my_func(name varchar(50), age int) returns void as $$
begin
    insert into person ("name", "age") values (my_func.name, my_func.age)
    on conflict ("name") do update
    set age = my_func.age
    where person.name = my_func.name;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It gives me the error:

```
my_func('Alex', 31);

ERROR: column reference "name" is ambiguous
```

I can't understand where is **this ambiguous "name"**? I tried `INSERT` and `UPDATE` separately, they work fine. What should I change in my function in order to make it work correctly?

**Notice**: I would like to keep the same names for the columns and arguments of the function.

Comment: Don't use the same name for parameters and columns. but `on conflict (person.name)` should work

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree, it can be a solution, but in some cases it's not acceptable.

Comment: that is perfectly acceptable - it's actual good (and highly recommended) coding style. Using the same names for columns and parameters is strongly discouraged and considered bad coding style

Comment: `on conflict (person.name)` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently not a bug, but there is no way to resolve the conflict using the default variable conflict resolution behavior: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAE3TBxyCn9dOF2273ki%3D4NFwsaJdYXiMQ6x2rydsWY_6p8z_zg%40mail.gmail.com

> This is not a bug. It's a naming conflict due to having a parameter
> and a column with the same name (a).
>
> You can use different name for the parameter or tell Postgres how to
> resolve such conflicts:
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.testf(a int)
> RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
> $body$
> #variable_conflict use_column
> BEGIN INSERT INTO testt(a) SELECT testf.a ON CONFLICT (a) DO NOTHING; END
> $body$;
> ```
>
> See the documentation:
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html

The key part is adding `#variable_conflict use_column` to the function to resolve the conflict without having to change the parameter name or reference the constraint name instead of the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise I see no reason why the current code shouldn't work; yet that seemes to be the case. I got it working through creating a names constraint and referencing it in the ON Conflict clause.

```
create table person (
    id serial not null,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    age int not null,
    constraint person_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint person_name_uk unique (name)
);

-- 
create or replace function my_func(name varchar, age int) returns void as $$
begin
    insert into person (name, age) values (my_func.name, my_func.age)
    on conflict on constraint person_name_uk
    do update
       set age = excluded.age
    where person.name = excluded.name;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

select my_func('George',35);
select * from person;

select my_func('George',45);
select * from person;
```

Still, it's strange!